# Generate custom init method automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, init

Is it possible to generate custom init method automatically from Xcode, as Android Studio does  for android?
I mean, if I declare some properties in .h, for example: 
    int a;
    int b;

So, I would like to create automatically a init method as:

```
- (id)initWithA:(int) aInner andB:(int) bInner
{
     a = aInner;
     b = bInner;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

New Xcode (after Xcode 10) support this issue for class (not for struct).

Steps:

1. right click on class name
2. click "refactor"
3. click "Generate Memberwise Initializer"

[image]

As for struct. You can make it class first, and change it back to struct after you get auto-gen init.

Comment: Quick note for structs- if you're not doing any extra logic in the initializer, it will be implied. Thanks for showing me where to find this for classes.

Comment: @Wu: Amazing solution. I wonder how did I never know this shortcut. Thank you!! And I tried for the structs. It worked without changing it to class.

Comment: Xcode 13 can generate memberwise initializers for structs as well. Not only for classes.

Answer (score 8):

While there's still no way to do this automatically (without installing a plugin), there's a neat trick to convert a list of property declarations to assignments using multiple cursors:

- Copy the list of properties and paste it into your constructor
- Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click to insert multiple cursors (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> work as well)
- Edit with multiple cursors to assign values

[image: multi cursor]

Credits go to Paul Hudson: [Xcode in 20 Seconds: Multiple cursors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aav96a2Ir78&index=33&list=PLuoeXyslFTuYQ9Hoh42Bw8sPYMlTOV0V7&t=0s)

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way of doing this, however you can install XCode extensions that will add support for this.

See this following extension as this will provide the feature you are after (Swift version).

https://github.com/Bouke/SwiftInitializerGenerator

Comment: I tested it and is working great. This is the only solution that it really works.

Answer (score -2):

Yo can create a snippet. You need to play with it a bit, create nice blue placeholders where relevant but most importantly, attach a keyboard shortcut to it. For example "initx"

Then you just start to type the shortcut in line where you want the initialiser to be and voila, you have your custom init.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can initialise an class by custom init method or you can pass parameter when you want to initialise class with custom init method

look

Define in your class.h file

```
 @interface CustomView : UIView 
   - (id)initWithA:(int) aInner andB:(int) bInner
```

In .m file implement initWithStringMethod.

```
 - (id)initWithA:(int) aInner andB:(int) bInner
       {
        if((self = [super init]))


        return self;
        }
```

initialised class from other class or viewController

```
 CustomView *cv = [[CustomView alloc] initWithA:5 andB:10 ];
```

Comment: The OP said "generate custom initialiser automatically by Xcode". 
Where in your suggestions is automatic generation? Your example is a manual (by hand) implementation.